# select all id's where values are different

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce DB
Products are stored in rows where each row has:
post_id (int not unique)
meta_key (varchar)
meta_value (double)

I am trying to find all post_id where the value of meta_key which equals to "_price" is different from the value of meta_key which equals to "_sale_price".

This is what I tried which of course didnt work

```
SELECT  * FROM `yai_postmeta`
where meta_key = "_price" <> meta_key = "_sale_price"
```

Comment: sample data expected results appreciated.  I for one don't understand the qeustion and sample data expected results may help clairify.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't use \`backtick\` identifiers

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the `post_id` values then this might be what you are looking for:

```
select distinct yp.post_id
  from yai_postmeta as yp
  where exists (
    select 42
      -- Take pairs of rows from the table.
      from yai_postmeta as Lyp inner join
        yai_postmeta as Ryp on
          -- The two rows refer to the same   post_id   as the outer query.
          Lyp.post_id = yp.post_id and Ryp.post_id = yp.post_id and
          -- One row's key is   '_price'  and the other's is   '_sale_price' .
          Lyp.meta_key = '_price' and Ryp.meta_key = '_sale_price' and
          -- The values for the two keys aren't equal.
          Lyp.meta_value <> Ryp.meta_value );
```

Runnable, with extended sample data ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8b65217907b84bd99b9197290f42103)):

```
declare @yai_postmeta as Table
 ( post_id int, meta_key varchar(20), meta_value varchar(20) );

insert into @yai_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value ) values

  -- Fails: Prices are equal.
  ( 7, '_price', 'USD13.95'),
  ( 7, '_height', '0.8 furlong'),
  ( 7, '_sale_price', 'USD13.95'),

  -- Passes: There is a masmatched price pair.
  ( 13, '_price', 'USD13.95'),
  ( 13, '_price', '10/6'),
  ( 13, '_sale_price', 'USD13.95'),

  -- Fails: One price is missing.
  ( -1, '_depth', '6 feet'),
  ( -1, '_area', '0.75 barn'),
  ( -1, '_sale_price', 'USD13.95'),

  -- Passes: Prices are different.
  ( 0, '_price', 'USD13.95'),
  ( 0, '_width', 'pinky'),
  ( 0, '_sale_price', 'arm & leg');

select distinct yp.post_id
  from @yai_postmeta as yp
  where exists (
    select 42
      -- Take pairs of rows from the table.
      from @yai_postmeta as Lyp inner join
        @yai_postmeta as Ryp on
          -- The two rows refer to the same   post_id   as the outer query.
          Lyp.post_id = yp.post_id and Ryp.post_id = yp.post_id and
          -- One row's key is   '_price'  and the other's is   '_sale_price' .
          Lyp.meta_key = '_price' and Ryp.meta_key = '_sale_price' and
          -- The values for the two keys aren't equal.
          Lyp.meta_value <> Ryp.meta_value );
```

Comment: Thank you, i have tested this code which seems exactly what i needed but for some reason i am unable to compare the post _id in the inner join to the out join
(also missing ".post_id" in the Ryp compare, 
          Lyp.post_id = yp.post_id and Ryp.post_id = yp.post_id and

i get an error : Unknown column 'yp.post_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @IB. Yup, I lost a `.post_id` in there. I've corrected that and added a runnable example (+dbfiddle) that uses even more sample data than you provided.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example

I assume the missing part of the puzzle is that i am running on mysql DB, still i get an error #1054 - Unknown column 'yp.post_id' in 'on clause'

Any idea what am i missing ?

Comment: Well, I suppose that it's possible that changing the database from T-SQL (assumed to be SQL Server) to MySQL could break things. Simply flipping the dbfiddle to MySQL 8.0 causes it to fail on the first line (`declare @yai_postmeta as Table`). [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5e807dd735ca2295f31b5d19ce33a14) dbfiddle seems to work in MySQL.

Comment: Amazing tool, i didnt know it so first of all thank you for the website
My DB is mysql 5.7 so that is why i get error (no results)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a5e807dd735ca2295f31b5d19ce33a14

Comment: Well, that's a freakshow. Here is the [MySQL 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4d3aace19805fc0f8ca7cfc22caaab81) dbfiddle. There's something about resolving the outer reference in an `on` clause that doesn't work reliably, but moving it to a `where` clause works. I'll just back away slowly and go back to SQL Server. It's elegance is shown by a demonstration of [simple arithmetic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bd87253fba69e516834988b0e87f197).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean?

show records where the _sale_price is different than the _price of the same post_ID.  I assume the absence of a corresponding record is different. or if both values are null that's "different"

```
SELECT coalesce(A.post_ID, B.Post_ID) as Post_ID, A.meta_value,  B.Meta_value
FROM `yai_postmeta` A
FULL OUTER JOIN `yai_postmeta` B
  on A.post_ID = B.post_ID 
 and A.meta_key = '_price
 and B.meta_key = '_sale_price'
WHERE A.meta_value <> b.Meta_value 
   OR A.meta_value is null 
   OR B.meta_value is null
```